# I can't submit my App store App because it doesn't see the assets folder. What is the solution?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a rookie. I'm new to swift. that's why I can't do some things. I need your help. What should I write in my plist file so that I can access the assets folder and transfer my application to the app store store. I have a simple application on this link, it is my first attempt. I want to send this to the app store. Can you [download](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jcuJbhmnbWVo63H11Rwr8NZ53nB4Wmzx?usp=sharing) and check my application or can you make the solution in the application and forward it to me? Very happy if you help.

Problems:

```
-"App Store Connect Process Error ERROR ITMS-90704:" Missing Application Icon. PNG format 1024 An app icon of x1024 pixels must be added to the Asset Catalog of apps created for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, it cannot be submitted for review
-Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90023: "Package icon is missing. .png format for iOS versions of iPad Pro, does not include an app icon exactly '167x167' pixels for iPad To support older operating systems, including icon maker.plist in the next package from Allah catalog
```

Comment: did you added app icon?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project is missing the "**Assets.xcassets**" folder(directory). so this might be the error you are facing

Comment: Do I need to write the "Assets.xcassets" folder to the info.plist file?

Comment: No you do not need to add it in plist file

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the below things

1. Make sure the `Assets.xcassets` is there is project.

[image]

2. Verify that in your project target (under `Deployment info`) For App Icons and Launch Image option **AppIcon** is selected. Please refer the following screen shot.

[image]

3. Does app icon is added in `Assets.xcassets`?.

You need to add App icon with 1024 x1024 size with non-transparent  background.

*NOTE: Transparent background will not be working as it will throw error while uploading.*

[image]

Comment: thanks I added 1024 * 1024 images but my image icons are not white

Comment: White bg is not required any bg other than transparent will be ok. Means There should not be a transparent bg.

Comment: only the background is yellow and in png format. I wonder if I do jpg?

Comment: can you download an application and see (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jcuJbhmnbWVo63H11Rwr8NZ53nB4Wmzx?usp=sharing)